# Finding center point of opened QGIS application using PyQt

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, pyqt5, center, qpoint

How can I find the center point of the opened QGIS application by means of PyQt?

By center point I mean this red cross in the middle of my screen where I have opened QGIS, see the image below.

[image: window]

I though, that this can be a possible solution, but `x_, y_` values look too small for me.

```py
from qgis.utils import iface
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPoint

main_window = iface.mainWindow().rect().center()
x_, y_ = main_window.x(), main_window.y()
point = QPoint(x_, y_)
print(point) #PyQt5.QtCore.QPoint(839, 493)
```

Comment: When QGIS is full-screen, I get `959, 504`. Which, allowing for the Windows task bar (positioned at the bottom), seems to be reasonable for the center of the screen (on a 1920, 1080 screen).

Comment: Compared with the mainwindow-size I also get reasonable values with your code:
`PyQt5.QtCore.QPoint(839, 498)

iface.mainWindow().size() -->

PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(1680, 997) `

Comment: Hi Taras, not sure if it helps, but you can check [this link](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/application-windows.html#window-geometry) which explains some of the widget internal geometry methods. `rect()`, `size()` etc excludes the window frame. To include the window frame you can use `iface.mainWindow().frameGeometry().center()` which returns a `QPoint` object.

Comment: What about `QApplication.desktop().screen().rect().center()`?